# DesignOnly attribute does not hide a property in runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

I'm building a custom web control with a public property which I only want to be available in design time (i.e. make it unavailable in code behind).
The `DesignOnly` attribute promises to do just that, but when I set `[DesignOnly(true)]` it has no noticeable effect whatsoever:

```
[Bindable(true)]
[Category("Appearance")]
[DefaultValue(null)]
[Localizable(false)]
[DesignOnly(true)]
public string MyProp
{
    get
    {
        return ViewState["MyProp"] as string;
    }


    set
    {
        ViewState["MyProp"] = value;
    }
}
```

The property **still** appears in code behind IntelliSense. Setting a value to it in code behind **works**. In these respects, the behavior is just as if the attribute had never been set. And I've cleaned and rebuilt the complete solution. Twice.

Am I doing it wrong? Can you please tell me what is the right way to go about this, then?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The DesignOnly attribute promises to do just that

Actually, no; it tries to make it clear when accessing it in code **isn't** available; if you lie (i.e. claim that something is design-only when it *is* available) then you should expect it to misbehave. The compiler knows what is available, and this design-only attribute is not defined in the C# spec, so it makes no difference to the compiler if you add this attribute.

Try adding:

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
```

which the code editor (IDE) looks at (but only when using a separate assembly) - note that this doesn't stop you using it - it just hides it.

I believe the MSDN text is trying to describe the difference between properties that *actually* exist on code, vs properties that only *pretend* to exist; you can actually do all sorts of things to make fake properties appear in the designer, and it is these *pretend* properties that might be marked as design-only.

Comment: Thanks! That was enlightening. So I gather that there's no way to control the actual availability of a property in a way which is dependent on the current mode (design/runtime)?

Comment: You can make code properties unavailable to most designers by using things like `[Browsable(false)]`; and you can make *true* designer-only properties by using a custom property model, but that is an advanced topic and involves understanding `TypeDescriptor`, `PropertyDescriptor`, `ICustomTypeDescriptor`, `TypeConverter`, etc- - very complex.